# Howto transpose multidimensional array in place

Tags: algorithm, multidimensional-array

how to transpose a 2D matrix in place?

Comment: square or not?
it makes a big difference

Comment: @aaa: Transposing a non-square matrix in place does not make a lot of sense.

Comment: Though depending on the representation (for example using a single array of N*M dimensions) it could be done.

Comment: This was pretty much "beaten to death" in [this post](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3062974/in-place-permutation-of-a-array-follows-this-rule)

Comment: @Jens It makes a lot of sense if you store all matrix data in one single array.

Answer (score 7):

Wikipedia had an article In-place matrix transposition. The article covers non-square matrices.

http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/In-place_matrix_transposition

Answer (score 6):

```
for (int i=0; i<n; i++) {
  for (int j=0; j<i; j++) {
    temp = a[i][j];
    a[i][j] = a[j][i];
    a[j][i] = temp;
  }
}
```

Comment: WARNING! This is only correct for square arrays. See @dlb's Wikipedia link below for a non-square matrix implementation.

Answer (score 4):

You have not specified a language, but generally, what you do is:

```
let a be your array.
for each i,j with i<j switch a[i,j] with a[j,i]
```

Comment: This too is only correct for a square matrix. Handling non-square matrices is surprisingly difficult.

Answer (score 2):

To get the transpose of a square matrix we need to consider elements above the main diagonal or below it and swap each with its reflection along the main diagonal:

```
for i->0 to N-1
 for j->i+1 to N-1
  swap matrix[i][j] with matrix[j][i]
```

Answer (score 1):

```
for(i=0;i<N;i++)
  for(j=0;j<N;j++)
    if(i!=j && j>i)
      {
        temp=a[i][j];
        a[i][j]=a[j][i];
        a[j][i]=temp;
      }
```

(`N` is the size of your array)

Answer (score 0):

Why bother ?  Just swap indices in any access statement.

Comment: There is a serious performance penalty for accessing 2D arrays in the "wrong" order - it's often better to pay the price of a transpose in order to get the benefits of contiguous memory access (unit stride).

Answer (score 0):

in c#

```
string[,] Value;
//fill Value

//create transposed array
ValueAux = new string[Value.GetLength(1),Value.GetLength(0)];
for (i = 0; i < Value.GetLength(0); i++)
{
  for (j = 0; j < Value.GetLength(1); j++)
  {
    Valueaux[j, i] = Value[i, j];
  }
}
```

The result is in ValueAux

Answer (score -1):

This seems to work well:

```
function transpose(a)
{
  return Object.keys(a[0]).map(function (c) { return a.map(function (r) { return r[c]; }); });
}
```